# Remove certain part in url when opening pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm attempting to make a file download site at the moment.
    Currently, if you go to

```
localhost/site/file/download/download.php?=CODE
```

it will take 
    you the designated page with the download link etc.

I'm trying to remove the

```
    file/download/download.php
```

part to have

```
 
   localhost/download/CODE
```

but i can't seem to get it working (so i can use it for my website).
    Here is my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /upload_main/file/download/

RewriteRule ^(download)/(\w+)/?$ $1.php?download=$2 [L,QSA]

# to take care of css, js, images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule ^download/(.+)$ /download/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use the URL `https://example.com/CODE`, then why does your pattern try to match "download" in the path? It is not there...

Comment: But instead of changing that pattern I would suggest to _keep_ it and change the idea of the URL you want to use for download to _indeed_ use such pattern: `https://example.com/download/CODE`. This will simplify things a lot, since you will struggle to tell download attempts apart from other requests to your site without that "download" in the path.

Comment: @arkascha Apologies. I do want it to be website/download/CODE but i dont know how to get it working corretly. All I keep getting is "object not found"

Comment: Your original URL path based on the file system structure appears to be `/site/file/download/`, so what is with `RewriteBase /upload_main/file/download/`?

Answer (score 0):

Given the changed desired final URL you settled on based on the comments to the question this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?download/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /site/file/download/download.php?=$1 [QSD,END]
```

That should work in the actual http server's host configuration and likewise in a top level distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). You should definitely prefer the first placement, but there are exceptions where you have to use a distributed configuration file, although that has clear disadvantages.

Comment: I have set the above in my .HTACCESS but when I visit localhost/site/file/download/code it shows 'Object not found'. If I appended the /?download=code it works.

Comment: Also just out of curiosity, where am I meant to be storing the .HTACCESS and the download.php that handles the request?